# Formatar campo numerico com 2 casas deciamais no datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Preciso mostrar uma coluna no datagridview coluna de peso bruto esse formato 0.00, mas não estou conseguindo, esta coluna não e criada em nenhum banco de dados, eu criei a coluna direto no datagridview, já fui nas formatações numéricas da coluna, deixei como N2, e mesmo assim nada de formatar a coluna.Preciso que quando eu digite um número decimal na coluna, EX digito 10 quando sair da célula, precisa mostrar 10.00

Segue meu codigo:

```
    private void btn_xml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string FileName = @"C:\Xml_Entrada\" + txt_chave.Text + ".xml";
        List<ClasseItensXml> ListaItens = new List<ClasseItensXml>(); //A lista é do tipo ClasseItensXml
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(FileName);
        var proditens = doc.GetElementsByTagName("prod");

        foreach (XmlElement nodo in proditens)
        {
            ListaItens.Add(
                 new ClasseItensXml()
                 {
                     CodigoProduto = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("cProd")[0].InnerText.Trim(),
                     NomeProduto = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("xProd")[0].InnerText.Trim(),
                     QuantidadeComercializada = nodo.GetElementsByTagName("qCom")[0].InnerText.Trim()
                 });

            //Repare que cada "nodo" é um item, portanto só adiciona um ClasseItensXml na lista.
        }

        dgw_Xml.DataSource = ListaItens; //por fim, usa a lista de source

        dgw_Xml.Columns["PesBruto"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "N2";
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Jovem, te peço do fundo do meu coração, formate o código desta pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coluna que você criou, não tem nenhuma propriedade associada, assim o DataGridView trata como uma string e não formata com o `N2`.

Você pode alterar sua classe `ClasseItensXml` para adicionar a propriedade `PesoBruto` e associar essa coluna:

```
public class ClasseItensXml
{
    public string CodigoProduto {get;set;}
    public string NomeProduto {get;set;}
    public string QuantidadeComercializada {get;set;}
    public decimal PesoBruto {get;set;}
}
```

O restante permanece igual, mas agora o DataGridView sabe que se trata de um tipo numérico e faz a formatação.

> Não se esqueça de associar a coluna à propriedade com o `DataPropertyName` e a formatação você também pode fazer pela interface gráfica do visual studio.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rovann, mais uma vez..